# Passing Data in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
    let cellText: String

    //need this to give the category which is clicked to the main view controller 
    // so its sends the data from one tableview to the other
    let categories =  cat[indexPath.row]
    cellText = categories.cat!
    let choosenCategory = cellText
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTableView", sender: choosenCategory)
    let user = "Anton"
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTableView", sender: user)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goToTableView")
    {
        let destination = segue.destination as? ViewController

        destination?.passedData = sender as? String
        print("open second one")
        destination?.passedUser = sender as? String
        print("Sender Vlaue: \(sender)")
    }
}
```

Hey there!
I need some help. I want to pass datas between my `tableviewcontroller`s.

My problem is when I pass the data between those two it opens it twice. So at first it loads the `Controller` with the `passedData` and afterwards with the `passedUser`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` twice.  Each call creates a new destination viewController.  You need to pass your setup data in one call.

One option would be to update properties in your viewController to hold the values instead of sending the data as `sender`.

Another way would be to create a structure to hold the values.  This would work well if you had variables of various types.

Since you only have two pieces of data and they are both `String`, you can pass them in an `[String]`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
    let cellText: String

    //need this to give the category which is clicked to the main view controller 
    // so its sends the data from one tableview to the other
    let categories =  cat[indexPath.row]
    cellText = categories.cat!
    let choosenCategory = cellText
    let user = "Anton"
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTableView", sender: [chosenCategory, user])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToTableView"
    {
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? ViewController else { return }
        guard let info = sender as? [String] else { return }

        destination.passedData = info[0]
        destination.passedUser = info[1]
        print("Sender Value: \(sender)")
    }
}
```

Comment: okay thank you. I already thought that is something like that! 
Cheers!